# How can multiple private keys be used with ssh?

Tags: ssh, authentication

I was able to setup ssh to use private/public key authentication.  Now I am able to do

```
ssh user@server1
```

And it logs on with the private key. Now I want to connect to another server and use a different key.  How do set it up so

```
ssh user@server1
```

uses privatekey1

```
ssh user@server2
```

and uses privatekey2

Comment: No real reason - ones a personal mythbox and the other is a work server and I didn't want to use my home key at work.

Comment: none of the answers seem to answer the full quesiton, eg, how to create different keys privatekey1 and privatekey2

Answer (score 52, accepted):

There are a few options.

1. Load both keys into your ssh agent using `ssh-add`. Then both keys will be available when connecting to both servers
2. Create your `$HOME/.ssh/config` file and create a `Host` section for server1 and another for server2. In each `Host` section, add an `IdentityFile` option pointing to the appropriate private key file

Comment: ssh agent was a great idea, also if I have both the public and private key files, ie key1 and key1.pub, in ~/.ssh it will automatically load them.

Answer (score 62):

You can set this up in your `~/.ssh/config` file. You would have something like this:

```
Host server1
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key_file1

Host server2
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key_file2
```

`man ssh_config` is a reference

Comment: You can also specify `User` for each host to cut down on key strokes. Lastly when you're generating a new SSH key for each host with `ssh-keygen` make sure you actually enter an alternate key path.

Comment: Is there an option to specify a default key, like saying `host x ->key1` and then the rest of the hosts `key2`

Comment: Yes, use
```sh
    Host *
```
And add the defaults, than overrides van be added underneath. Also:
```sh
    man_ssh_config
```
Specifically the part in the "Host" section with regards to asterisk '*' &  exclamation mark '!'

Answer (score 2):

Besides the (preferable) option of adding both keys in `$HOME/.ssh/config` (note that this requires appropriately setting attributes of `$HOME/.ssh` and `$HOME/.ssh/config`), you can use

```
$ ssh -i privatekey1 user@server1
```

e.g.

I learned this by way of solving this more complex situation:
[Multiple ssh access types from a given user1/client to the same user2/server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/949470/multiple-ssh-access-types-from-a-given-user1-client-to-the-same-user2-server)